# How to make objects inside objects block Subsurface Scattering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, subsurface-scattering

As we all know inside the human skin the bones, veins and other denser fluids absorb the light more than the soft parts. I want to create the same effect without using textures since they are in a 2D space and break the illusion of a sub-dermal effect. Is there anyway to fake it in a realistic way with volumes or something I need to try to achieve the effect in a purely physical way.

Comment: Can you add screenshots to your question or answer? There is the Subsurface Scattering option of the Principled BSDF that can simulate the light that enters the skin and scatters. I wonder why you need objects that block SSS? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and what the point of this question is, nor where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed an actual hollow space, faked it with a solidify modifier and joined the other objects I wanted to block the light with to the original mesh.